# Using a jQuery Plugin (flipclock) in an angular.js application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am fiddling around with AngularJS and have to include a jQuery plugin called [flipclock.js](http://flipclockjs.com/). I googled a lot and found this [article](http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/) about wrapping jQuery in an Angular directive.

I looked at it and did the same with `flipclock` - looking like this

```
var app = angular.module('flipClock', []);
app.directive('FlipClock', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $(element).FlipClock(scope.$eval(attrs.FlipClock));
        }
    }
});
```

with the following markup

```html
<div ng-App="flipClock">
    <div id="countdown" class="countdown" flipclock="{}"></div>
</div>
```

but nothing is happening, i get the Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Base is not defined - flipclock.js:37
```

And :37 is just `FlipClock.Base = Base.extend({ ...`

The order of the source in my html is:

```
<script src="components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<!-- build:js scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/pre.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->

<script src="components/flipclock/libs/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="components/flipclock/flipclock.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you found a way ? loo0king for it too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directive definition name is case-sensitive.  It's mismatched against the name in the HTML. Try changing:

```
app.directive('FlipClock', function(){
```

to

```
app.directive('flipclock', function(){
```

and

```
$(element).FlipClock(scope.$eval(attrs.FlipClock));
```

to

```
$(element).FlipClock(scope.$eval(attrs.flipclock));
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the feedback - i fixed that, but its still the undefined base...  also i tried to change the source order, but nope. 
The plugin is also working in its jquery syntax. 

I've got no idea ...

Comment: Does it work if you reproduce one of the examples on the site without Angular? I downloaded the flipclock package and it looks like `Base` is defined in another file, `base.js` in `js/libs`. Maybe verify this file is there in the `libs` subfolder.

Comment: That did the job - okay, its still not working, but the base error is gone. thank you - havent seen the obvious :)

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe post a new question with updated plunker/jsfiddle if it's still not working.